# Running VLC from a cronjob: How to get a DBUS connection?

Tags: xorg, d-bus, vlc, headless

I'm trying to run VLC headless from a cron job. The idea is to grab single images from a RTSP stream every two minutes and (later, and in another script) ftp them to a distant machine. The command line I use is (added linebreaks for clarity):

```
vlc -I dummy rtsp://somesourceaddress/
--rate=1 --vout=dummy
--video-filter=scene --start-time=0 --stop-time=1 --scene-format=png --scene-prefix=img1 --scene-path=/tmp/ --scene-replace 
vlc://quit
```

However, while this works beautifully from a terminal window inside an X session, running this from cron results in the following error message:

```
[0x81d1154] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus 
session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon 
without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0x81d1154] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x81d15fc] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x80503fc] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" 
initialization failed
[0x81d15fc] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
```

So, where can I obtain suitable values for $DISPLAY if there is none? Or how can I create the DBUS connection manually?

Comment: have you tried the `-d` switch to run in daemon mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are these errors really fatal, i.e. do you still get the output you want?

1. The `$DISPLAY` error message probably only concerns **screensaver inhibition**, adding `--no-disable-screensaver` *could* solve it (otherwise you can probably ignore it, it's non-fatal).  VLC shouldn't need a D-Bus connection for what you're trying to do.
2. You could also try using `cvlc`, which apparently doesn't use any interface (this sounds like it's related).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the meaning of the "inhibit interface error". It turned out to be non-fatal, indeed. I did not try cvlc since I need to run the controlling script as root, so I use vlc-wrapper already and did not want to complicate things further.